# Prove that if $V$ is a finite dimensional inner space and $V=U \oplus W$ then $V=U^{\perp} \oplus W^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, direct-sum

I've tried many different ways and each time I get lost in the way.
In the previous (related) questions I have proven the following:

1. $(U+W)^{\perp} = U^{\perp} + W^{\perp}$
2. If $V$ is finite dimensional then $(U \cap W)^{\perp} = U^{\perp} + W^{\perp}$

Maybe one of those might help...

Comment: First prove that $U^{\perp} \cap W^{\perp} = \{0\}$. Then, use a dimension argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there is a common element $v \in U^{\bot} \cap W^{\bot}$, then we have
$$v^T u = 0, v^T w =0$$
for all choices of $u \in U$ and $w \in W$
Now $v$ itself can be written as $v = u_0 + w_0$ for some $u_0 \in U$ and $w_0 \in W$. Hence:
$$v^Tv =v^T(u_0+w_0)=0$$
It follows that $v=0$ is the only common element.